# Let us pick the sound of chat ping

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, audio

Getting ping'd in some chatrooms (servers?) makes a nice little *ding!*, in some others you get a loud *bonk!* Inconsistency is evil, this needs to be fixed.

Or rather, instead of forcing a uniform *bink!* on all chat users across the network, how about making the ping notification sound a configurable *preference*?

We can already choose to have sound on or off. I propose to expand that into something like...

- (off)
- *Ding*
- *Bonk*
- *Lightsaber swoosh*
- *Knock-knock*

Would that be feasible?

Comment: And, for the love of Deity, if you implement this, make it user-bound and not client-bound.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2479/se-chat-custom-notification-sound

Comment: Oh my god! Yes! You do not know how much I hate that obnoxious chat.se sound! It's dreadful!