# How can a chat notification sound change be requested?

Tags: support, chat, audio

Having recently used Tavern on the Meta chat room for the first time, the room has the best and not-one-bit annoying notification sound when being tagged.

On the Aviation site, it's horrible. Not to mention the double/triple ding when the original message is edited. So it's become sort of an etiquette to not @ someone a lot.

I understand the sound can be switched off or the tab muted, but how can one request the Tavern's sound be applied to any site's chat?

Comment: Support this FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273874/let-us-pick-the-sound-of-chat-ping

Comment: @rene: If by support, you mean UV, just done so, thanks :)

Comment: Also, you can control the volume with this script I wrote: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227028/audio-slider-for-chat-pings